# What does "pin a native member" mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm having a problem compiling some code under MSVS 2010 and I am getting a C2678 error.  I found a description of that error here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ys0bw32s(v=vs.100).aspx

But I don't understand what is meant by "pin a native member".

Can someone explain?

Here is part of the code that generated that error:

```
#pragma once

#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <memory.h>

template<typename callbackCodes_e, callbackCodes_e endOfCodes, typename param_t>
class CCallbackContainer
{
    typedef std::function<void(param_t)> callback_t;

public:
    struct callbackInfo_t
    {
        callbackCodes_e code;
        callback_t callback;
        param_t param;
        size_t countdownToAutoDelete;
    };

    CCallbackContainer() {};
    ~CCallbackContainer() {};

    typedef std::function<void(param_t)> callback_t;
    typedef callbackInfo_t HANDLE;

    std::vector<callbackInfo_t> m_Callbacks[endOfCodes];
    void callbackCall(callbackInfo_t const & callbackInfo);

public:
    inline bool validCode(callbackCodes_e code) { return code < endOfCodes; }

    HANDLE callbackSet(callbackCodes_e code, callback_t callback, DWORD param, size_t countdownToAutoDelete = 1);
    void callbackClear(HANDLE callbackToRemove);
    void callbackCall(callbackCodes_e code)
    {
        auto callbackList = m_Callbacks[code];
        for(auto i: callbackList)
        {
            i->callback(i->param);
        }
        for_each(auto i = callbackList.rbegin(); i != callbackList.rend(); ++i)
        {
            if (--(i->countdownToAutoDelete) < 1)
            {
                callbackList.erase(i);
            }
        }
    }
};

// template implimentation has to be in header file
template<typename callbackCodes_e, callbackCodes_e endOfCodes, typename param_t>
typename CCallbackContainer<callbackCodes_e, endOfCodes, param_t>::HANDLE // return
    CCallbackContainer<callbackCodes_e, endOfCodes, param_t>::callbackSet // function name
        (callbackCodes_e code, callback_t callback, DWORD param, size_t countdownToAutoDelete) // parameters
{
    ASSERT(validCode(code));
    callbackInfo_t callbackInfo = { code, callback, param, countdownToAutoDelete };
    ASSERT(std::find(m_Callbacks[code].begin(), m_Callbacks[code].end(), callback) == m_Callbacks[code].end());
    m_Callbacks[code].push_back(callbackInfo);
    return callbackInfo;
}

template<typename callbackCodes_e, callbackCodes_e endOfCodes, typename param_t>
void // return type
    CCallbackContainer<callbackCodes_e, endOfCodes, param_t>::callbackClear // function name
        (typename CCallbackContainer<callbackCodes_e, endOfCodes, param_t>::HANDLE callbackToRemove) // parameters
{
    callbackCodes_e code = callbackToRemove.code;
    ASSERT(validCode(code));
    auto iCallbackInfo = std::find(m_Callbacks[code].begin(), m_Callbacks[code].end(), callbackToRemove);
    ASSERT(iCallbackInfo == m_Callbacks[code].end());
    m_Callbacks[code].erase(iCallbackInfo);
}

template<typename callbackCodes_e, callbackCodes_e endOfCodes, typename param_t>
void // return type
    CCallbackContainer<callbackCodes_e, endOfCodes, param_t>::callbackCall // function name
        (callbackInfo_t const & callbackInfo) // parameters
{
    callbackInfo.callback(callbackInfo.param);
    if (--callbackInfo.countdownToAutoDelete < 1)
    {
        callbackClear(callbackInfo);
    }
}

template<typename callbackCodes_e, callbackCodes_e endOfCodes, typename param_t>
void // return type
    CCallbackContainer<callbackCodes_e, endOfCodes, param_t>::callbackCall // function name
        (callbackCodes_e code) // parameters
{
    auto callbackList = m_Callbacks[code];
    for(auto i: callbackList)
    {
        i->callback(i->param);
    }
    for_each(auto i = callbackList.rbegin(); i != callbackList.rend(); ++i)
    {
        if (--(i->countdownToAutoDelete) < 1)
        {
            callbackList.erase(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The error, however actually was generated by something in algorithm:

```
14>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(41): error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'CCallbackContainer::callbackInfo_t' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
14>          with
14>          [
14>              callbackCodes_t=CBalloonHelp::callbackCodes_t,
14>              endOfCodes=eCallbackEnd,
14>              param_t=DWORD
14>          ]
14>          could be 'built-in C++ operator==(std::_Bool_type, std::_Bool_type)'
14>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\functional(277): or       'bool std::tr1::operator ==(std::tr1::_Unutterable,const std::tr1::function &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
14>          with
14>          [
14>              param_t=DWORD,
14>              _Fty=void (DWORD)
14>          ]
14>          c:\projects\cv-7646\og50\include\gxcoll.h(67): or       'BOOL operator ==(const GXNDX &,const GXNDX &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
14>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\guiddef.h(192): or       'int operator ==(const GUID &,const GUID &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]

// ... other operator==() tests that didn't match the signature.
```

It looks to me like there is a problem with the default operator==() for callbackInfo_t, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I think this is only for C++/CLI, not for C++, and that Microsoft simply lumped them together for implementation and documentation purposes. But I'm not entirely sure, it's possible that the same problem also exists for C++ in a way I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pinning is a term used in C++.NET. It is used when a ref'ed class (those declared with `ref class`) needs to access some native member variable, you have to *pin* it because managed references can be moved around in memory, but native pointers have to stay in fixed places. Once you *pin* the member variable you get a native pointer and all goes normally. When the object is *unpinned* it will be movable again. For more details search for the `pin_ptr<>` template.

But your code doesn't have any `ref class` at all, so the *pinning* comment is just misleading you!

Your problem is simply that you didn't provide an `operator==()` to your `callback_t` struct!

Just do this, or whatever is more appropriate for your situation:

```
 struct callbackInfo_t
    {
        callbackCodes_e code;
        callback_t callback;
        param_t param;
        size_t countdownToAutoDelete;

        bool operator==(const callbackInfo_t &o) const
        {
           return code == o.code && callback == o.callback &&
                  param == o.param && countdownToAutoDelete == o.countdownToAutoDelete;
        }
    };
```

But note that, obviously, any of the member variables that you compare must be comparable, too, or the code will fail again with a similar message.

Comment: It's true that I didn't put that in the code that I posted, but I still got the same message when I made a similar function. Actually, that was the first thing I did.  Thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: There is no such thing as *"C++.NET"*. Pinning is not related to any particular language either. It is a concept required to access managed objects from native code in the context of a compacting garbage collector.

Comment: @IInspectable: Actually, it is called C++/CLI, the MS dialect of C++ to be used with the .NET framework (should I say CLI?). About pinning, yes, it is a concept, but in the context of C2678 it is clearly referring to the use of `pin_ptr` in C++.